# Can't seem to get chrome.contextMenus.onClicked to fire in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write my first browser extension and I can't seem to get the click-handler to fire with a context menu item is clicked. The console.log calls don't seem to spit anything out to the console, and I tried using alert() just in case the "background" scripts (not sure what the difference between background and content scripts is exactly yet), but that didn't seem to do anything either.

When I select some text in an input in my test page, right-click and select either Encrypt or Decrypt, nothing happens; not in the console or in the network tabs in developer tools. What am I doing wrong?

**manefest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "my name",
    "description": "my description",
    "version": "1.0",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "js": ["content_script.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "contextMenus",
        "http://my.hostname.com/"
    ]
}
```

**background.js:**

```
/**
 * A handler which will run the analysis of the DOM element's selected text
 */
function clickHandler(info, tab) {
    "use strict";
    console.log(info);
    console.log(tab);
    // get selected text as encrypt/decrypt
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, "get selection", null, function(selection) {
            var data = {
                "action": action,
                "selection": selection
            };
            var max_length = 4095;
            if (data.selection.length > max_length) {
                data.selection = data.selection.substring(0, max_length);
            }
            var url = "http://my.hostname.com/";
            jQuery.post(url, data, function (response) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, response);
            }, "json");
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Create a context menu items to allow encode/decode
 */
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        "id": "encrypt",
        "title": "Encrypt",
        "type": "normal",
        "contexts": ["editable"]
    });

    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        "id": "decrypt",
        "title": "Decrypt",
        "type": "normal",
        "contexts": ["selection"]
    });

    chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(clickHandler);
});
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to move contextMenus.onClicked outside onInstalled.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
 //create context menus
})
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function() {
 //handle context menu actions
})
```

"Register to receive any events your extension is interested in each time the event page is loaded. The event page will be loaded once for each new version of your extension. After that it will only be loaded to deliver events you have registered for. This generally means that your event listeners should be added at the top level scope of the event page, otherwise they may not be available when the event page reloads. If you need to do some initialization when your extension is installed or upgraded, listen to the runtime.onInstalled event. This is a good place to register for declarativeWebRequest rules, contextMenu entries, and other such one-time initialization."

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#best-practices

Comment: Thanks for replying! I actually had the code that way before I created this ticket. I just figured that creating the click event before creating the context menu items seemed backward. But I just did as you suggest - left the two contextMenus.create items in the onInstalled and moved the contextMenus.onClicked out of onInstalled - but I still get the same behavior...which is no feedback in console or in network tabs.

Comment: Are you using the console for the background page? (accessible from chrome://extensions)

Comment: Well, I'm using console on the page that I'm trying to run this from. Does the background.js file run in a separate console than the page I'm looking at when i run the contextMenus item? I assumed because it's running against the page I'm looking at, console.log would appear on that console...but it sounds like that's an incorrect assumption.

Comment: No, it is a separate console.

Comment: OK, strange...when I click on the "inspect views: background page" I get a developer tools window that launches, and I see errors in there. I think I'm back on track - thank you! But now I'm getting nothing in my response callback from that sendMessage in my clickHandler. I have this in content_scripts.js and I don't see anything in either consoles: chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) { console.log('here'); sendResponse('something'); })

Comment: You should be using runtime.onMessage but that problem sounds like a separate question.

Comment: I thought you had to use 'chrome.extension' in content scripts, that objects like 'chrome.runtime' were only for background scripts. But it looks like I got the instructions from this page inverted: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: Unfortunately, switching to chrome.runtime doesn't solve the ultimate problem. The listener in content_scripts.js never gets called - the callback in the background.js sendMessage just returns with an undefinedresponse without th elistener in content_scripts.js doing anything.